# Multi-Select List of contacts on Customer Record

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to create a multi-select field on the customer record whereby the user can select which of the customer's contact will receive an email notification etc...

Have created a custom entity multi-select field, but cannot get it to filter to only show the current customer's contacts.

I've tried filtering:

Company *compared to field* Company
Company Name *compared to field* Company Name
Name/ID *compared to field* Company *or* Company Name

I either get **no** contacts, or the list is populated with **every** contact regardless of whether it's linked to the company.

[image: ScreenSchot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This screenshot is self-explanatory, but I need to enter text to allow sumission...

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!